# Browser won't show psuedo element on a local project - but will if I use a local server

Tags: css, svg, pseudo-element

When I use Codekit to watch my project folder, the psuedo elements in the file below are shown by the browser. All good.

However if I load the index.html file just from the browser, the psuedo elements don't show.

There is no back end on this project, just a simple html/css site.

```
.social-media__icons::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;

    mask-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;

    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;

    /* The first value is the original svg size in the file. */
    width: calc(24px / 1);
    height: calc(24px / 1);

    background-color: green;

}

/* sourcing individual icons */
.social-media .facebook::after {
    mask-image: url(assets/svg/facebook.svg);
    -webkit-mask-image: url(assets/svg/facebook.svg);
}
```

Also if I use a simple svg background image on one of the elements directly, the svgs can be loaded just by the browser ie.

```
/* This one is all good */
.social-media .facebook {
    width: calc(24px / 1);
    height: calc(24px / 1);
    background-image: url(assets/svg/facebook.svg);
}
```

I concluded from this that the problem isn't the file path, or the svg files themselves, so must be something about the psuedo elements.
What have I got wrong?

Comment: Look at the network tab, there must be failing request for the image

Comment: Network tab seems to get stuck loading the site. Primed cache just has Please wait...